# django sql-server 2008 sp2 and sql-server 2012

Tags: python, django, django-models

There are some backends for django model to be used with sql-server, but all of them are outdated and cannot be used for newer versions of sql-server. Is there a simple manual to create a backend myself to work with sql-server newer versions?

Comment: Did you try to use one in particular and run into problems?

Comment: Sure, I found 2 or three of them and one of them works with 2008 and Django 1.3 but not later versions, so I've encounter 2 versioning problems Django and sql-server

Comment: I know of multiple projects which are running Django 1.4 against sql-server 2008 rc2. But what I meant was did you try to use any of the backends with sql-server 2012 and run into errors or are you just assuming they don't work because the README doesn't explicitly say it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some brief instructions on using Django with SQLServer 2008 on my blog at:

http://doingstuffwithdjango.blogspot.co.uk/

I've used django-pyodbc with Django 1.4 and SQLServer 2008 successfully.